# Compatible versions of the classes org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase and javax.servlet.ServletContext error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, netflix-eureka

I have the following `pom.xml`:

```
<!--  Copyright (c) 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  -->
<!--  Licensed under the Universal Permissive License v 1.0 as shown at https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/upl/  -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accounts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accounts</name>
    <description>Account Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.19.0</liquibase.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-spring-boot-starter-ucp</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle-spring-boot-starter-wallet</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.lra</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile-lra-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.rts</groupId>
            <artifactId>narayana-lra</artifactId>
            <version>5.13.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And when running my Spring application I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1201)

The following method did not exist:

    'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The calling method's class, org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/app/classpath/account-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.class

The called method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/app/classpath/account-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/app/classpath/account-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.75.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: jar:file:/app/classpath/account-0.0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase and javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

If I comment out this section the application starts:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>
```

I'm not sure what could be wrong, I'm guessing some version issues but I can't figure what? I've tried all kinds of 3.x versions for the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` but no difference.

Anyone seen this before an can help?

Thanks
Andy